# Object creation mocking mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

i have a class top and bottom. i want to unit test the atom class which create the object of bottom.

```
public class top {

  publiv top() {
     bottom b = new bottom("value");
  }
}
```

Unit test class:

```
public class topTest {
   @Test
   public void test(){ 
     top a = new top();
   }
}
```

while creating a object for top class in test, it will create a object for bottom class.

Here, i want to mock the bottom class object creation. Could anyone help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

For doing so you should consider to pass the bottom object as parameter. It is always a good practise to pass objects as parameters when an objects are depending on that object.

```
public class Top {
   private Bottom bottom;

   public Top(Bottom bottom) {
      this.bottom = bottom
   }
}

public class TopTest {
   @Test
   public void test(){ 
      Bottom bottom = mock(Bottom.class);
      Top top = new Top(bottom);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the logic creating the instance of bottom somewhere. Either in an overrideable method like:

```
public class top {

  public top() {
     bottom b = new bottom("value");
  }

  protected bottom createBottom() {
     return new bottom("value");
  }
}
```

And then you can override it in the test:

```
public class topTest {
   @Test
   public void test(){ 
     top a = new top() {
            protected bottom createBottom() {
               return Mockito.mock(bottom.class);
             }   
             };
   }
}
```

Or you create a BottomCreator class pass it to Top in construction time and use a mocked/fake version when you test it.

```
public class top {

      private final BottomCreator bottomCreator;

      public top(BottomCreator creator) {
           this.bottomCreator = creator;
      }

      public top() {
         bottom b = bottomCreator.newBottom();
      }

    }
```

Comment: why passing a bottomcreator as constructor parameter instead of passing a bottom instance?

Comment: I guess that depends on semantics. Maybe Bottom must/should be created inside Top, I tried to give a suggestion that changes as little as possible the mechanics described in the original question. But it can work by passing it in too.